# Change GroupBox Header location

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have the following `GroupBox` whose text sits on the border of the control.  Currently, half of the text is inside and half is outside the control.

How can I move it to sit completely inside the control?

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Background="LightSteelBlue">
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <Label FontSize="15" 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            FontFamily="Calibri" 
            FontWeight="ExtraBold">Traceability Data</Label>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a margin or padding to your label like this:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Background="LightSteelBlue" Margin="0,-20,0,0" >
      <GroupBox.Header>
           <Label FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Calibri" Padding="0,20,0,0" FontWeight="ExtraBold">Traceability Data</Label>
      </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

Padding seems to give a better results.

Comment: With margin and Padding , GroupBox control moves down from above control. I am looking solution that will maintain location of the GroupBox.

Comment: You could always have a negative margin on your GroupBox, it works fine on my side. I have edited my answer to include it.